# Opening routines in phpmyadmin is too slow

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a lot of procedures and functions in routines and everithing was working fast until i create procedures with 900 lines of code. It is simple procedure with many if conditions. Execution takes about ten seconds.

**Problem:**

When i click routines in phpmyadmin it takes 3 minutes just to open list od routines.

When i click edit or execute that routine it takes 3 minutes to make action.

The other routines are opened immediately when i click edit or execute.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: phpMyAdmin can be horribly slow to open. I have moved over to HeidiSQL https://www.heidisql.com/ Very straightforward and very quick to load. Local DB loads in a couple of seconds. Remote DB pretty quick too. Well worth a look.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer but I can't use any tool which i must connect to server because it is closed environment.